# Copy text from an input field and save it into a variable with python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

How do I get the text from inputs without value attribute with Selenium? The problem is that they are filled automatically (maybe with JavaScript) when the page loads and the text doesn't appear on the html so I can't find anything that represents it.

[image]

Comment: Do you need a way to extract text without using value or is this rather a timing issue?

Comment: A way to extract it without using value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a module called [win32clipboard](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32clipboard.html), which is part of [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) solved my problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import win32clipboard

element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a') #highlight all in box
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c') #copy

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
text = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData() #paste
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

print text
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the text is in the box, you can access it using `WebElement.get_attribute('value')` where `WebElement` is the text box that you want to extract the text from.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own expected condition.  The following works

html/js:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("string").value = "hello";
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <input id="string" type="text" value="">

</body>
</html>
```

python:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class regex_to_be_present_in_element_value(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, regex):
        self.locator = locator
        self.regex = regex

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            element_text = EC._find_element(driver,
                                         self.locator).get_attribute("value")
            if element_text:
                return re.match(self.regex, element_text)
            else:
                return False
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
                return False

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("file:///path/to/the/htmlfile.html")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        regex_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, "string"), "he*")
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

It simply waits until there is text in the value attribute of the specified element matching the regex generated by the regex string passed to the constructor, in this case simply "hello". "he*" matches "hello".

I used this as a guide in making the class: https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#text_to_be_present_in_element_value